# How to treat ImageShack

Tags: discussion

See [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising).

I've just approved 3 edits involving ImageShack.

We have tools to look for these images (see the above discussion). The question is, how to attack this?

- Divide and conquer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only were there not many, Emrakul had already taken care of most of them. I approved a couple still-pending edits and finished the rest.

Everything listed here is now fixed:
http://data.stackexchange.com/cooking/query/340339/posts-with-images-hosted-on-imageshack

and after next data update presumably that query will start returning no results.